# Vue (2.6.14) - v-for not displaying data with an api import (axios)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

**The idea**
I'm trying to build a display where activities are shown with some filters. The data comes from an API generated by the CMS. The filters are not shown in the code since its not relevant.

**Problem**
When manually defining the 'items' in the data property the v-for list rendering displays fine and gives the desired output. When pulling the data from the api and assigning them to items the v-for is not displaying anything.

**My Thoughts**
I think that the v-for is run before the api request is finished putting the data into the 'items' value. Currently I'm using 'created' property to fire the function, also used 'Mounted()' before, this also didn't work.

**Versions** Vue 2.6.14, Axios 0.21.1

**Vue Code**

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: null,
    },
    created: function () {
        this.fetchData()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function() {
        axios
            .get('/api/activities.json')
            .then(response => (this.items = response.data.data))
        }
    }
})
```

**Templating**

```
<div id="app">
    <ul class="example">
        <li v-for="item in items">
            {{ item }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: As `vue.js` is reactive it would rerender your `<li>` items, when `items` changes. So I guess your response maybe is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be working just fine. Look below, I just replaced your api call with a dummy `REST` api call and it's working just fine. Please console out the data from `response.data.data` and see if you are really receiving an array there.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false


let vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        items: null,
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchData()
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData: function() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {  this.items = response.data })}
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div id="app">
    <ul class="example">
      <li v-for="item in items">
        {{ item.id }} - {{ item.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```